# TypeError: variable is undefined despite being able to log the variable correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to get a simple list of lessons contained in a course from an endpoint.

If I try `console.log(this.state.course.lessons)` an array contained 3 items is displayed.
However,if I try `console.log(this.state.course.lessons.map(//function)` I keep getting

> TypeError: this.state.course.lessons is undefined

How can I map a function to the lessons array so I can render them as a list.
component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export class CourseDetail extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        course: []
    };
}
componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/courses/${this.props.match.params.id}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((course) => {
            this.setState({
                course: course,
            });
            console.log(this.state.course.lessons)
        });
}
render() {

    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.course.lessons.map((lesson)=>(console.log(lesson)))}
            <h1>{this.state.course.title}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
}

export default CourseDetail
```

json returned from end point

```
{
"id": 1,
"lessons": [
    1,
    2,
    3
],
"owner": 1,
"rating": 0,
"title": "Course 1",
"description": "course 1 desc",
"pub_date": "2019-11-23",
"is_live": false,
"category": 1
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most obvious solution would be just to give the object a default state if you want to access it:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        course: {
            lessons: []
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: thanks this works. Just for understanding sake, my error was assuming that because lessons was contained in the json result that react would be able to access it right ?

Comment: @uhexos If lessons is not defined and you call map on it, it will complain because map doesn't exist on undefined. It's basically a nullpointer. In your example lessons would only be set on response of the ajax call later.

Comment: Note that your code is not fool proof; if the server doesn't return a response that has the expected format, you will run into bugs.

Answer (score 1):

The problem on your code is the life cycles (Mount-> Render-> DidMount), and in this render, u have not fetch the data yet.

You can try this:

```
render() {
    if (!this.state.course.lessons) return null //this line
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.course.lessons.map((lesson)=>(console.log(lesson)))}
            <h1>{this.state.course.title}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: this just prevents the error page and does nothing to help get the items from the array

Comment: Is this way that im work with react for 2.5 years :3, like u have to wait your data to fetch for finally put the data on the component .-., but i think that is depend of the situation so, if it doesnt help sry :), maybe the other way is better so idk

Comment: I get it now, thank you. The page gets rendered before there has been a chance to fetch the data.